# How to check same string value for multiple properties and shorthand if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Basically if any of the value in `mailPrice` contain `N/A` or 'n/a` trying to return true its not happening looks like i am missing something , Also if there is any better approach instead of writing big if condition i would appreciate ?

main.js

```js
const drug = {
  "isBrand": false,
  "drugName": "Hydr",
  "drugStrength": "5mg-300mg",
  "drugForm": "Tablet",
  "mailPrice": {
    "costEmployer": "0.0",
    "costToday": "N/A",
    "deductible": "n/a",
    "memberCopayAmount": "0.00",
    "penalties": "N/A",
    "totalDrugCost": "0.00"
  }
}

const priceFilterHandler = (item) => {
  let bRet = false;
  if (item.mailPrice.costEmployer === "N/A" || item.mailPrice.costEmployer === "n/a" || item.mailPrice.costToday == "N/A" || item.mailPrice.costToday === "n/a" || item.mailPrice.penalties === "N/A" || item.mailPrice.penalties === "n/a" || item.mailPrice.deductible === "N/A" || item.mailPrice.deductible === "n/a") {
    bRet = true;
  }

  return bRet;
};

console.log(priceFilterHandler(drug));
```

Comment: Your code works correctly.

Comment: @Pointy thanks there was issue in my local that fix the error , Any help on second part of my question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an array of possible values and rewrite it as follow:

```
const na = ["N/A", "n/a"];

if (na.indexOf(item.mailPrice.costEmployer) != -1 
    || na.indexOf(item.mailPrice.costToday) != -1
    || na.indexOf(item.mailPrice.penalties) != -1
     || na.indexOf(item.mailPrice.deductible) != -1) {
  ...
}
```

This can be useful if you have different conditions that can be applied for na, for example

```
 const na = ["N/A", "n/a", "na", "NA", "n.a."];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` and `some`:

```
Object.keys(drug.mailPrice)
      .some(prop => drug.mailPrice[prop].toLowerCase() == 'n/a');
```

Edit based on your comment:
If you want to exclude certain properties, you can use `filter`

```
Object.keys(drugz.mailPrice)
    .filter(prop => !['memberCopayAmount', 'totalDrugCost'].includes(prop))
    .some(prop => drugz.mailPrice[prop].toLowerCase() == 'n/a');
```

Comment: i only want to check those specific field we can get other fields in mailPrice that could contain NA but i dont want to return true in that case

Comment: I don't think it really matters, but see the updated answer

Comment: object is big contain alot of properties i just summarized to understand better, we can not exclude large number of properties i believe

Comment: well, you can also reverse the filter and list the properties that should be included, but that kinda defeats the point of using Object.keys. If there is no 'rule' by which you can separate the properties, there is no other way than to list them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way using `.some`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

```
const priceFilterHandler = (item) => {
  return Object.keys(item.mailPrice).some(prop => item.mailPrice[prop].toLowerCase() === 'n/a');
};

console.log(priceFilterHandler(drug));
```

Comment: what would happen if it comes back with the value ?

Comment: if at least one of those properties is valued as `n/a` (insensitive case, as it checks with `.toLowerCase())` it will return true. if no one of them is `n/a`, it will return false

Comment: value could come as a number

Comment: that case `.some` won't evaluate as true, because it's not `n/a`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine but you can loop through the object and then check if the object contains N/A or n/a

```
      // loop through the mailPrice object
      Object.entries(item.mailPrice).forEach(entry => {
         if (entry[1].toString().toLowerCase() === 'n/a') {
          bRet = true;
          retrun;
        }
      });
```

Comment: i only want to check those specific field we can get other fields in mailPrice that could contain `NA` but i dont want to return true in that case